# Have to press ctrl + click and scroll mouse wheel to zoom in and out in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Have to press and hold ctrl + click and scroll mouse wheel in VS Code to zoom in and zoom out. I have also enabled the "Mouse wheel zoom" option. But I have to click the middle button(scroll button) and scroll to zoom. Any Solution?

Answer (score 5):

Seems like this is available already, you just have to add the below setting to your `settings.json`:

```
"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true
```

Comment: where i could find this `settings.json` ? where add `"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true` ?

Comment: works for me if i put it here `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` : https://i.imgur.com/3YvF6gI.png

Answer (score 1):

To add or change to code `font size`, you need to add custom keybinds to your `keybindings.json` file. Here's how you do that in `vscode`.

- First open the command palette using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Then type and select:

> >Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)

- Finally append these lines at the *bottom* of your JSON file, and save it

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+oem_minus",
  "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+oem_plus",
  "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn"
}
```

---

##### These add key bindings for zooming in and out the text only.

- **Zoom in:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+**<kbd>+</kbd>**

[image]

- **Zoom out:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+**<kbd>-</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That worked! But I was wondering if I can add mouse wheel scroll as a key bind.

Comment: @priyaaanshu I don't think mouse keybinds are available yet in vscode. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: It looks like it isn't possible. There is [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38849) asking about the possibility of mouse keybinds that has been open for over a year, revealing that there is currently no way to do it.